# Runtime permissions in capsulated objects - how to handle properly?

Tags: android, permissions

I was wondering, how to handle the runtime permission in capsulated objects.

So, let's say we have a loggerobject which needs to write to disk.
The only thing the objects should do is writing to the disk.

Shall this object also handle runtime permissions?
Shall the object be in the beginning unable to write (by a flag) and the flag will swap if we get the permission?

I will be glad to know, how some of you do this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission is granted for the whole app, not for individual objects.

If you get the permission for your app once, you don't need to request it again and again.

In your case you can check and request the necessary permissions before writing to a file or even before the creation of your object.

The best practice is to request the permissions in the context just before using the features which require the permissions.

Check my library for handling permissions easily. Just get a reference of context and you can request permissions from anywhere.

https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: Yes, I know the permission is granted for the whole app.
I just want to check if permission is granted right before I need it.

Your library looks handy.
Thanks a lot. And apache 2.0 license <3
I ll give it a try

Comment: Yes, I will mark it.

Thanks, the library is really helpful so far!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no one clear answer for your question. Your question is related to the software architecture in general. So there might be a lot of different opinions. I will give you mine.

Often times you want a class to have a single responsibility and do only one job. Therefore, a logger only logs messages but it doesn't care a lot about permissions.

So I would say it's often a question about how to design your API and make it easy to work with.

For example, let's say we have an interface for Logger:

```
interface Logger {
    void d(String tag, String message);
}
```

Then we introduce a concrete implementation called `FileLogger`:

```
final class FileLogger implements Logger {
    @Override
    public void d(String tag, String message) {
        // write a message to a file somehow
    }
}
```

The question here is should `FileLogger#d` fails with `SecurityException` if the permission has not been granted yet? Or should it just warn a developer somehow?

Personally, in this case I would modify `FileLogger` to not fail if the permission has not been granted yet, but the permission itself must be granted in another part of the application.

```
final class FileLogger implements Logger {
     @Override
     public void d(String tag, String messsage) {
         if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              // write a log to a file
         }
     }
}
```

Let's take a look at another example. Imagine we have an interface called `LocationApi`:

```
interface LocationApi {
    @Nullable
    Location getLastLocation();
}
```

A user must grant a permission to the application so it can obtain his last location. Is it a critical to fail immediately if the app doesn't have a permission? I would say yes!

The implementation of this interface would look something like this:

```
final class LocationApiImpl implements LocationApi {
    @Nullable
    public Location getLastLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(..) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            throw new SecurityException();
        }
        // obtain a location
    }
}
```

P.S. There is a special annotation [RequiresPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RequiresPermission.html) that can help you to indicate that a method requires a permission, otherwise it might throw `SecurityException`.

Then we can modify `LocationApi` interface like this:

```
interface LocationApi {
    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    @Nullable
    Location getLastLocation();
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your answer. You are right, it is a question of the software architecture.

I was wondering, how you would catch and handle the exception, when you are developing a library and you want to handle the exception at runtime in the ui class - let's say the activity.

Comment: It depends. If you want to use the `LocationApi` interface described above then in an activity I will check for a permission first and then call the appropriate method. I don't think it's a good idea to build your logic around `SecurityException` and handle permissions once this exception is thrown.